# This site can’t be reached:localhost refused to connect

Tags: xampp, localhost

I am trying to open the index of my C:\xampp\htdocs folder, but when I try:

> localhost:8000
> or
> localhost:8000/index

It shows:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost refused to connect.
> Search Google for localhost 8000 index

How can I open index of htdocs folder on my browser?

Even when I tried :

> localhost:8000/wordpress

It showed same error:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost refused to connect.

I don't understand what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

make sure you have xampp turn on, also check if thers any error xampp shows

make sure your are using right port ie. localhost:80000 u can check it with config file

Comment: xampp server in on, and xampp server isn't showing any error